# How to run Sample projects directly from developer site in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

i am trying to run sample projects from [Samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Wiktionary/index.html)
from developers site of android.but i am unable to run it..can any one give me suggestions or idea how to run that sample project directly in Eclipse????

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow [instruction on this page](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/get.html), to download the source to your computer. And then, in Eclipse, 
 1. File -> New -> Project
 2. Android Project -> Click next
 3. Click the radio button: "Create project from existing source" and browse for the root folder of the source
 4. Finish

In case those are official demos (like wikitionary you mentioned) and you installed everything in SDK, in step 3 you can probably select "Create project from exisiting sample" and once you pick the api level, you can select the sample right in the drop down.

Answer (score 5):

Why u want to run sample projects from developer site? 
This projects available in your AVD.

**For Example:-** Create **New Android Project** -> checked **Create Project from existing Samples** and choose any sample project ,see image for your help
[image]

Click finish create your sample project.

Answer (score 0):

first download the sample in your machine the import the sample project in eclipse and run it.
let me know if you still have issues.